# Counting rows on indexed column is slower than on primary and normal column?

Tags: mysql, count, query-optimization

I wonder why this could happen? I have a simple table with a primary key `Id` column, an indexed column `A` and some other normal columns (of `datetime`) and all fields have non-null value.

When I try counting the rows on the primary key column like this:

```
select count(Id) from my_table
```

It takes about 0.4 seconds to return the value (a total of about 1.1M records).

I tried the same query but for a normal (`datetime` as mentioned before) column, it takes almost the same time (actually a bit slower).
But when I tried the same query on the indexed column `A`, it takes up to 1.2 seconds to return the count:

```
select count(A) from my_table
```

The `A` column index info (if any needed for your inspection):

```
type:        BTREE
Allows NULL: Yes
Unique:      No
Packed:     (empty)
```

Could you give me some explanation to this issue? could we do anything to improve it better?
I cannot count on other column because actually I have to count distinctly on that column so the returned count has a different meaning for each column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found this answer myself just by guessing and trying it out. I've tried altering the column `A` to make it NOT NULL (it's nullable before), after that the `count` on that column is just normal again like other columns (indexing is not involved here at all).

It's just simple like that :)

Comment: Good for you -- Experimenting is a good way to learn.  (I have done a lot of experimenting in my learning of MySQL.)  However, there is a risk -- You might jump to the wrong conclusions.  See if what you discovered agrees with my Answer.

Answer (score 1):

The fastest is `COUNT(*)`.  The `*` is a convention; it does not mean "all columns".  `COUNT(1)` is equivalent.

Use `COUNT(col)` when you want to exclude any rows where `col` is `NULL`.  (This is rarely needed.)  If `col` is declared `NOT NULL`, then it is really a waste to include `col`.  (Note: I said *declared*; you said something different: *have non-null value*.)  According to `Allows NULL: Yes`, you declared the column `NULL`, hence `COUNT(col)` *will* check every `col`.

What happens with `COUNT(*)`:

- For a count without a `WHERE`, the Optimizer picks the 'smallest' index and walks through it.  The `PRIMARY KEY` is always(?) the largest, so it is usually shunned.  The reason for this algorithm is that it assumes it will have to read the entire index from disk; I/O is slow; and "smaller" means less I/O.
- If there is a `WHERE` clause, then the optimal index is determined by what is in the `WHERE` clause -- that is a huge topic unto itself.

It is a good idea to say `NOT NULL` unless you have business logic that calls for `NULLs` ("not yet specified", "optional", "deleted", "Not Applicable", ...)  There are several cases (most are obscure) where a `NOT NULL` performs slightly better than `NULL`.

Caveat:  My Answer applies to InnoDB, but not totally to MyISAM.

Comment: thank you for your answer, this provides some other helpful info for me as well.

Comment: @Hopeless - While you were upvoting this Answer, I was adding to it.  Check the additions.